# Recent Apps shows app contents even though when its locked

Tags: security, privacy, recents-screen

I am trying to figure out how to hide an app from being seen when you hit the recent apps button.

I use ZDBox's app lock to hide my apps and files when needed but noticed that when I hit the recent apps button the app is perfectly visible in its last viewed state (resulting in not so much privacy).

Has anyone found a solution for this?

Update : Still haven't found any solution for this yet :( Below are some discussions I bumped into while searching for it on the web

[Is there a way to hide an application permanently from Recent apps history in ICS?](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1698969)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We've encountered this problem on a previous project I was on, a big banking application.

For added security we made the app to automatically log-out after five minutes of inactivity. We found it disturbing for the user that Android OS would still show your personal account info in the Recent Apps overview. This would be visible until you really closed the app, rebooted your Android or returned to the app and exited it on a screen without any banking info.

After quite some research we found out that Android (since ICS, so Android 4.0 and up) is using the internal screenshot feature to capture the screen for use in Recent Apps. There seemed to be no user option available to prevent this, only the developer of an app can [restrict this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9822076/how-do-i-prevent-android-taking-a-screenshot-when-my-app-goes-to-the-background).
You can ask the devs of ZDbox to include this feature in their app or options by contacting them at service@zdworks.com

Just a heads-up: If a dev does this, then the screenshot goes full black. We decided to offer a placeholder image instead, so it doesn't look bugged to the average user, see bottom app in screenshot below.

Hope this info is still usefull to you! :)

[image: Bottom app is 'exited' with Home button at my account mutation overview, but showing no private information in Recent Apps.]

Answer (score 0):

You could use audio manager (actually a app hider) to lock apps, I have had no issues with it, it closes apps when you navigate out of them (press home or recents)

Comment: A link to the app you're recommending would be helpful, especially if it has a non-descriptive name.

Comment: Just search audio manager in the play store (top result, called 'hide it pro' now), I agree, links are useful, but when guaranteed search terms are more useful, either way link: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.smartanuj.hideitpro